# Font size much larger on Android Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I thought I turned off all of Bootstrap's responsive features following this post, but I found that the font size on mobile phones still seems to be responsive (or simply larger) and I'm not sure why.

Here's the desktop page: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

Here's the mobile page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g69aP.png

Notice how the body font size is much larger than the navbar font size, even though they're the same size on the desktop page.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should try to determine if the issue is that the navBar text is too small or the body text is too large.  It would help determine the course of action

Comment: It's definitely the body text that is too large.

Comment: Update: It has something to do with one of the paragraph `<p>` rules, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: Is it because you dont have the viewport set?  I know that you are intentionally not using it, but the current scaling on the site is inverse to anything I would expect from bootstrap (the text gets bigger as the screen gets smaller) (testing using Chrome device emulator)

Comment: No, I have no viewport set, as bootstrap says to do (if you don't want responsiveness).

Comment: @DarkNinja955 As a test, I added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` and it made the font size as it should be, but naturally, it made other things not as they're meant to be. So the question is, why is the font size changing with the viewport?

Comment: Your site has the following:
> Note the lack of the <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">, which disables the zooming aspect of sites in mobile devices.
Viewport does allow the site to zoom, but it works both ways (zoom in and zoom out).  So applying a viewport allows your site to scale properly to any screen size.  In this case, the viewport "zooms out" the site so that font is similar scale (not to be confused with size) to what it would look like on a desktop

Comment: And how would I remove that scaling then?

Comment: Have you tried setting [`-moz-text-size-adjust: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [cvrebert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3342739/cvrebert) suggested, the solution to this is adding the following to `body`:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
   -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        text-size-adjust: none;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust